# Virtual host doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have a ubuntu 16.04 running apache2 server which have multiple virtual host. and today i want to add a new virtual host.

After creating the directory for the site, I've created the virtual host configuration and enable it, then I reload and even restart `apache2`.

The problem is : 
The first time I access the site , it work (it open the html that i put to the directory for testing purpose)

But then if I reload it, it redirect me to the default virtual host of the server.

Here is the virtual host configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Every time I reload and restart apache it work the first time but after reloading it back to the default virtual host. this is actually the first ever problem that i encounter in configuring virtual host, because all other virtual host work just fine with the same configuration.

result of **apache2ctl -S**

```
port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.domain.com.conf:1) alias www.domain.com
```

tried adding Listen 80 on top of the config file, still no change.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @HBruijn done that , still no answer yet . do you mind to help analyze where is the problem ?

Comment: seems like this site has no visitor ?